# React-router route props not passed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-router

I am using componentDidMount to fetch data from firebase and set the components state with fetched data

```
  componentDidMount() {
  this.state.firebase.database().ref().on("value", function(snapshot) {
  let data = snapshot.val()

  // Authors
  this.setState({authors: data.Author})
```

then in render method I have this

```
{
    console.log(this.state.authors)
}
<Route path="/author/:authorId" component={AuthorPage} authors={this.state.authors} />
```

Inside AuthorPage component I have this

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props.route)
    return (....
```

The console output is

```
Object {authorId: Object} // This is for this.state.authors
Object {path: "/author/:authorId", authors: undefined, component: function} // this is for this.props.route
```

As you can see, this.state.authors has a value, but becomes undefined when passed to component as route props. This has never happened to me before, even in the same app with other routes.

Comment: do the `console.log(data.Author)` before `this.setState({authors: data.Author})` and check the value returned by that. are you getting any error ?

Comment: Nope, state is properly assigned, I checked React dev tools. Problem happens in router

Comment: same way is working at other places ? there is a alternative solution that i can suggest.

Comment: There are many alternates, thats not a problem, but why does this problem happen. Want to know that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this solves the problem

```
  let authorsArray = data.Author
  let aths = this.state.authors
  for(var j in authorsArray) {
    aths[j] = authorsArray[j]
  }
  this.setState({authors: aths})
```

Anybody know why?